# Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'd like to know the count of 'member_seq' to match the value of 'R_INFO.nick_name'.

How to get Count Data??

**SQL**

```
SELECT
    nick_name,
    REPORT.seq_no,
    report_type,
    report_item,
    contents,
    DATE_FORMAT(report_dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS report_dt,
    REPORT.status,
    question,
    E_INFO.status AS game_status,
    entry_fee,
    REPORT.game_seq,
    Count(member_seq)
FROM
    REPORT
LEFT JOIN R_INFO ON
    REPORT.member_seq = R_INFO.seq_no
LEFT JOIN E_INFO ON
    REPORT.game_seq = E_INFO.seq_no
GROUP BY R_INFO.nick_name;
```

Comment: Please include sample input and output data.  I can't figure out what you are trying to do here.

Comment: include the columns in group by REPORT.seq_no,
 report_type,
 report_item,
 contents,
 DATE_FORMAT(report_dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS report_dt,
 REPORT.status,
 question,
 E_INFO.status AS game_status,
 entry_fee,
 REPORT.game_seq,

Comment: 'How to get Count Data??' of what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I am confused because of my poor English. I worked hard to find out and worked it out like this way.

```sql
SELECT
    nick_name,
    REPORT.seq_no,
    report_type,
    report_item,
    contents,
    DATE_FORMAT(report_dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS report_dt,
    REPORT.status,
    question,
    E_INFO.status AS game_status,
    entry_fee,
    REPORT.game_seq,
    (SELECT COUNT(member_seq) REPORT WHERE member_seq = R_INFO.seq_no) AS count_member,
FROM
    REPORT
LEFT JOIN R_INFO ON
    REPORT.member_seq = R_INFO.seq_no
LEFT JOIN E_INFO ON
    REPORT.game_seq = E_INFO.seq_no
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't vouch for whether your JOIN logic is right, but to fix the error, as its text suggests, you need to remove all the columns that are not aggregated or grouped by. All these:

```
REPORT.seq_no,
report_type,
report_item,
contents,
DATE_FORMAT(report_dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS report_dt,
REPORT.status,
question,
E_INFO.status AS game_status,
entry_fee,
REPORT.game_seq
```

The query will become:

```
SELECT nick_name, Count(member_seq)
FROM REPORT
LEFT JOIN R_INFO ON REPORT.member_seq = R_INFO.seq_no
LEFT JOIN E_INFO ON REPORT.game_seq = E_INFO.seq_no
GROUP BY R_INFO.nick_name;
```